# Is the energy per degree of freedom $\frac{1}{2}kT$ in relativistic systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

The equipartition theorem says that the mean energy per degree of freedom is $\frac{1}{2} kT$. Is this result relativistically correct?

Comment: @Alexander that should be an answer

Comment: Wikipedia has some [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Extreme_relativistic_ideal_gases) and [more general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Anharmonic_oscillators) analysis. The result is that the energy per degree of relativistic velocity freedom is $kT$, not $kT/2$.

Comment: @Blackbody Blacklight this is for ultra-relativistic particles - photons (blackbody radiation) or massive particles such that $\frac{mc^2}{pc}\ll 1$. This result is good for this exrtreme conditions, yet - most of the relativistic regime is somewhere in between

Comment: @Alexander I was thinking that the "more general" part covers the in-between case, by polynomial approximation of $\sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}$, but really not… it assumes independent oscillators, which the components of the relativistic velocity vector aren't.

Answer (score 6):

The equipartition theorem is a mathematical consequence of very specific kind of Hamiltonians. It states that any 'squared' term of deegree of freedom in the Hamiltonian gets $\frac{1}{2}k_bT$ of energy (it is a statement about the energy distribution for this kind of Hamiltonians).

For example - classical ideal gas Hamiltonian - $H=\Sigma_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2m_i}(p_{i,x}^{2}+p_{i,y}^{2}+p_{i,z}^{2})$ has 3N of such terms and thus $E=\frac{3N}{2}k_bT$.

Relativistic (classical) Hamiltonian for a single free particle is $H=\sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}$. It has no 'squared' degrees of freedom, thus the equipartition theorem doesn't apply in this case. In the classical limit $H \approx mc^2+\frac{1}{2m}p^2$ - you retrieve the 'squared' term.

Comment: What comments would you offer on the problem 3.24 of Pathria's Statistical Mechanics? Can this problem be approached from a different perspective?